# Working with Android Broadcast on an Android App targeting Oreo

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, android-broadcast

I am planning to target my Android App to Oreo but the documentation mentions that implicit broadcasts are no longer allowed to be declared in Android Manifest. Few exception have been stated [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions).

I am using these broadcasts

```
<receiver android:name=".ABC">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".ABCD">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".ABCDE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".ABCDEF" />

<receiver
    android:name=".ABCDEFG"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Can anyone help me to know what of the above broadcast will not be allowed. And also what will happen If I continue to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and `android.intent.action.TIME_SET` are on [the  whitelist that you linked to](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions). Those broadcasts should work as it always has.

`android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` is not an implicit broadcast. It will be "broadcast" only to your app, via an explicit `Intent`. This should work as it always has.

Neither `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` nor `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` are part of the Android SDK, and so you would need to research those with whoever is defining and sending those broadcasts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. AFAIK `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` is called when the phone is rebooted/restarted & `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` is called when the phone is completely powered on. I have an alarm to set but if the phone is restarted then my alarm will be go off. Can you please clarify. Also from the start of the name `android.intent.action.` it looks like it should be of an Android OS but as you said it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: @RajeshK: "AFAIK android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON is called when the phone is rebooted/restarted" -- it is not part of Android. I can find no code in the Android 9.0 source, for example, that sends that broadcast. You will need to discuss it with the device manufacturer.

Comment: OK. Sorry but just one more question. Will `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETE` be called on restart/reboot of a phone? If no then will my alarm which is set be reset on restart/reboot of a phone.

Comment: @RajeshK: "Will `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETE` be called on restart/reboot of a phone?" -- yes, it is supposed to. Some manufacturers apparently allow users to control this via the Settings app, though I have not seen that myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. As usual all your answers have a good explanation and reasoning and they are to the point. Thanks once again.

Comment: After setting the target SDK Version to Android Oreo the `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` is never called. But I get this error `E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast sprd.intent.action.powerguru.PKG_CHANGED` can you please help.

Comment: @RajeshK: I have no idea what that `Intent` action is, sorry.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the reply